# How to parse a list with an optional separator at the end?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I'm writing a parser that processes a simple C header file with enums and structures. I have written a parser using Boost Spirit Qi, that almost does the task. I'm stuck with a problem that I can fix by a hack, but I'm curious if it's possible to solve it more accurately.

Enum's I'm dealing with are simple. Here is an example:

```
enum <optional enum name>
{
   VALUE1,
   VALUE2 = 222,
   VALUE3
}
```

The code snippet that parses such enums:

```
IdParser %= lexeme[(alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_')];
EnumExprParser %= lexeme[+(char_ - (lit(",") | lit("}")))];
EnumValueParser %= IdParser >> -('=' >> EnumExprParser);
EnumParser %= lit("enum") >> -IdParser >> lit("{") >> (EnumValueParser % lit(",")) >> lit("}") >> -lit(";");
```

Notice, that I parse enum values as a list separated by a comma. But sometimes the last enum value is ended by a comma too : `VALUE3,`. My dirty solution is the following: `*(EnumValueParser >> -lit(","))`

But this allows parsing several enum values without a separator. This is acceptable for me, but I'm interested in more clean solution. I'm parsing enums into the following structures:

```
struct EnumValue
{
    std::string Name;
    boost::optional<std::string> Value;
};

struct Enum
{
    boost::optional<std::string> Name;
    std::vector<EnumValue> Values;
};
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not make it a selfcontained sample? https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/

Comment: Done creating the self-contained example from your code. 19 minutes

Comment: @sehe Hey, nice job! But does my question really need a working sample? I think my problem is lack of knowledge and experience in boost.spirit. So I thought someone could point me at least a direction where to go. Looking through the spirit manual didn't help me much.

Comment: It's always about actual code for me. It's not very useful to try to reason about snippets out of context.

Comment: Maybe this one will help:
http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y-2011.html#enum_specifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quickfix would be to replace

```
EnumBody  = '{' >> EnumValue % "," >> '}';
```

With

```
EnumBody  = '{' >> -EnumValue % "," >> '}';
```

Though that's sloppy, because it would allow `enum X { a,,,b }` as well. So, this would be more accurate:

```
EnumBody  = '{' >> EnumValue % "," >> -lit(',') >> '}';
```

**NOTE** There's another catch you haven't spotted yet, and that's the empty enum body should be allowed too (`enum X {}`), so let's fix *that* too:

```
EnumBody  = '{' >> -(EnumValue % ",") >> -lit(',') >> '}';
```

#### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b2eee6b767b4fff)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace ast {
    using Id = std::string;
    using EnumEntry = std::pair<Id, std::string>;
    using EnumBody = std::vector<EnumEntry>;

    struct EnumDef {
        Id name;
        EnumBody members;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::EnumDef, name, members)

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, ast::EnumDef(), Skipper> {
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(Enum) {
        using namespace qi;

        Id        = raw [(alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_')];
        EnumExpr  = +~char_(",}");
        EnumValue = Id >> -('=' >> EnumExpr);
        EnumBody  = '{' >> -(EnumValue % ",") >> -lit(',') >> '}';
        Enum      = "enum" >> -Id >> EnumBody >> -lit(';');
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, ast::EnumEntry(), Skipper> EnumValue;
    qi::rule<It, ast::EnumBody(),  Skipper> EnumBody;
    qi::rule<It, ast::EnumDef(),   Skipper> Enum;
    // lexemes:
    qi::rule<It, ast::Id()> Id, EnumExpr;
};

int main() {
    using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    It f(std::cin >> std::noskipws), l;

    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, Parser<It>(), qi::space);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parse success\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f != l)
        std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

For the input

```
enum NAME
{
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2 = 222,
    VALUE3,
}
```

Prints

```
Parse success
```

Comment: Recorded live stream for the interested: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/delimited-list-with-optional-trailing-delimit/

Comment: Well, the solution looks perfect to me. In fact, we can parse `enum { , }` but that's not a problem for me, because the code I'm parsing is a valid C code. I also adapted some tips from your code: I wrote too much `lit` and I didn't need so many `Parser` words in the code. Thanks!

Comment: Also `%=` was a bit superstitious in the absense of semantic actions. I think you also didn't notice you didn't include `'_'` characters in the identifier names

Comment: I even don't know the difference between `%=` and `=` (in this context, of course). When I started writing my parser, I consulted the tutorial, but I didn't find a word about it, so I just wrote my code like it was there. Nevertheless, I will use `=`.

Comment: I found it in the text right now. Just didn't notice it at the first time

Comment: Can you explain EnumExpr above a bit? I'm confused with +- and underscore. I understand that you want to exclude , and } but that doesn't look like a difference operator. I understand + and - operators but not when put one after another. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, that's tilde, not minus sign! Still, I cannot find that operator in the documentation.

Comment: @Tony see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char.html#spirit.qi.reference.char.char.expression_semantics (it's obviously not a general parser operator; it only works on explicit character sets)